# Woocommerce's add_to_cart function returns false and doesn't add anything to the cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm working on a Woocommerce SPA (Single-Page Application) and I'm trying to add a product to Woocommerce's cart but it just doesn't work.

I'm doing this in a custom plugin. In a function that responds to an AJAX call using Wordpress' regular workflow for AJAX calls (`wp_ajax_nopriv_*`, `wp_ajax_*` and whatnot).

The problem is when I try to use the WooCommerce API (not the REST API, just the regular PHP API).

I'm calling:

```
$string = $woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart($id);
```

And I get `false` as a response.

I'm also calling:

```
$response['cart'] = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();
```

And I get an empty array in response.

I **do** have `global $woocommerce;` at the top of that function and I also tried using `WC()` instead.

None of that worked.

Tried clearing all caches too using WP Super Cache. Still nothing.

Keep in mind I'm quite inexperienced in both WP and WC, so I might be committing some very elementary mistake.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved the problem. The item wasn't being added because the product didn't have a price. That's all.

Comment: How did you add price to item?